# mysql insert table by python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert

I just want to insert the table list into the mysql database table. Here's the code:

```
import mysql.connector 
# Open database connection
a = [('apq3'), ('aquaporin')]
b = ["skin"]
c = ["down-regulated", "down regulation", "down regulate"]

def input_mysql(a1, b1, c1):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='xxxx',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='crawling')
    #sql = 'INSERT INTO crawling_result(search_content, content) VALUES(%s)' 
    sql_target_a = 'INSERT INTO a (term) VALUES(%s)'
    sql_target_b = 'INSERT INTO b (term) VALUES(%s)'
    sql_target_c = 'INSERT INTO c (term) VALUES(%s)'
    cursor=db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_target_a, a1)
    cursor.execute(sql_target_b, b1)
    cursor.execute(sql_target_c, c1)
    db.commit()
    db.close()

a_content = a
b_content = b
c_content = c
input_mysql (a_content, b_content, c_content)
```

After running, it keeps showed that "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement". Can some one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your lists - `a` and `c` - have more than one value, but you're only using one value in your statements `(%s)`. This is considered an error since it's unclear if the extra parameters were intentional or not.

If you intend to insert one row per element in the source arrays, use [`executemany`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) and pass in a sequence of parameters:

```
a = [('apq3',), ('aquaporin',)]
b = [('skin',)]
c = [('down-regulated',), ('down regulation',) ('down regulate',)]

[...]

# Insert two rows (one for each parameter list in `a`)
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO a (term) VALUES(%s)', a)
```

Comment: Thanks. So how could I insert the list with more than one value into the mysql.table? I only want to insert into the "term" column.

Comment: @Thomas.Q look at [executemany](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) perhaps? You would have to re-format your inputs into lists of tuples, though

Comment: Yes. JUST need change it as cursor.executemany(sql_target_a, [(x,) for x in a1]). And it works! Thx!